# Adobe Flash Player Installer runs in always on top mode obscuring other programs

Tags: windows-8, flash-player, always-on-top

Whenever an update for Adobe Flash is available, the Adobe Flash Player Installer runs in "always on top" mode obscuring other programs.

[image]

I have to drag it to a corner so that I can continue my work while it downloads the update. Is there a way make in *not* run in "always on top" mode? I am using Windows 8. I don't want to use auto-update as I want to keep a tab on my data usage.

Answer (score 0):

During [setup, select to use the background update](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/background-updater-windows.html), this updates Flash silently in background with the help of the task scheduler and you don't see any Window.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I knew about this option but as I said - *I don't want to use auto-update as I want to keep a tab on my data usage*.

Comment: in this case, you must life with it. I've set this option once and I'm always up to date.